# Quick Action removal from chatter

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component based Quick Action for a case object. When the chatter is enabled in an organization, this quick action is removed as a button and added as a tab in the chatter feed. How can this be disabled? The "enable actions in publisher" setting is not used.

Thanks

Comment: Does the quick action share the same name as a standard global action that appears in Chatter?

Comment: No, this does not seem to be the case. Sorry, for such a delay in my response. I completely missed your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes for case object, It's not the chatter enabled in Organization who makes the action coming as a tab in chatter tab on the Lightning record page.

It is the feed tracking who controls it on Case or Work Order Object. When you want to show action in highlight panel, You need to make sure to disable the feed tracking on Case object.

For more Information:- [Why Quick Actions are not appearing on Case page layout in Lightning Experience](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/why-quick-actions-are-not-appearing-on-case-page-layout-in-lightning-experience/)